# Firefox Snap crashes as soon as any video starts playing (23.04, Wayland)

Tags: firefox, snap, wayland, amdgpu, 23.04

I am using Firefox Snap on Ubuntu 23.04 in native Wayland mode and noticed that it crashes/ holds the whole system as soon as any video on Youtube starts playing.
I don't have any Firefox specific logs, because I can't move my mouse cursor anymore when this crash/ freeze happens, but I can show you my journalctl logs, if that helps anyone:

```
13:39:42 dbus-daemon: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Core" interface="org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor" member="GetIdletime" mask="send" name=":1.41" pid=6271 label="snap.firefox.firefox" peer_pid=3321 peer_label="unconfined"
13:39:42 firefox: [GFX1-]: GFX: RenderThread detected a device reset in PostUpdate
13:39:42 kernel: [drm] ring 0 timeout to preempt ib
13:39:42 kernel: [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* GPU Recovery Failed: -110
13:39:42 kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset end with ret = -110
13:39:42 kernel: [drm:amdgpu_device_ip_resume_phase2 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* resume of IP block <gfx_v9_0> failed -110
13:39:42 kernel: [drm:amdgpu_gfx_enable_kcq [amdgpu]] *ERROR* KCQ enable failed
13:39:42 kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: [drm:amdgpu_ring_test_helper [amdgpu]] *ERROR* ring kiq_2.1.0 test failed (-110)
13:39:41 kernel: [drm] kiq ring mec 2 pipe 1 q 0
13:39:41 kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is resumed successfully!
13:39:40 kernel: [drm] reserve 0x400000 from 0xf43f800000 for PSP TMR
13:39:40 kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset succeeded, trying to resume
13:39:39 kernel: [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Process information: process RDD Process pid 7424 thread firefox:cs0 pid 7677
13:39:29 kernel: [drm] ring 0 timeout to preempt ib
13:39:29 kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu:    RW: 0x1
13:39:29 kernel: gmc_v9_0_process_interrupt: 25 callbacks suppressed
13:39:29 rtkit-daemon: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
13:39:28 RDD Process: libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
13:39:26 dbus-daemon: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Core" interface="org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor" member="GetIdletime" mask="send" name=":1.41" pid=6271 label="snap.firefox.firefox" peer_pid=3321 peer_label="unconfined"
13:39:17 systemd: Started app-gnome-org.gnome.DejaDup.Monitor-7474.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
13:39:17 firefox: OnCloseSessionDone error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Object does not exist at path “/org/freedesktop/portal/desktop/session/1_120/firefox_firefoxpwa_681759248”
13:39:16 rtkit-daemon: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
13:39:16 dbus-daemon: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Core" interface="org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor" member="GetIdletime" mask="send" name=":1.41" pid=6271 label="snap.firefox.firefox" peer_pid=3321 peer_label="unconfined"
13:39:16 systemd: systemd-timedated.service: Deactivated successfully.
13:39:11 firefox: OnCloseSessionDone error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Object does not exist at path “/org/freedesktop/portal/desktop/session/1_120/firefox_firefoxpwa_3200885328”
13:39:11 dbus-daemon: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Core" interface="org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor" member="GetIdletime" mask="send" name=":1.41" pid=6271 label="snap.firefox.firefox" peer_pid=3321 peer_label="unconfined"
13:39:10 rtkit-daemon: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
13:39:08 snapd: storehelpers.go:773: cannot refresh snap "chromium": snap has no updates available
13:39:07 systemd: snap.chromium.hook.configure-82f786df-a485-44b9-8498-2db8b77f3f01.scope: Deactivated successfully.
13:39:06 dbus-daemon: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Core" interface="org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor" member="GetIdletime" mask="send" name=":1.41" pid=6271 label="snap.firefox.firefox" peer_pid=3321 peer_label="unconfined"
13:39:02 5: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap-update-ns.chromium" name="/var/lib/snapd/" pid=7255 comm="5" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
13:39:02 systemd: tmp-snap.rootfs_yMyiNj.mount: Deactivated successfully.
13:39:02 dbus-daemon: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Core" interface="org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor" member="GetIdletime" mask="send" name=":1.41" pid=6271 label="snap.firefox.firefox" peer_pid=3321 peer_label="unconfined"
13:39:02 systemd: snap-chromium-2614.mount: Deactivated successfully.
13:39:02 udisksd: Error getting 'loop2' autoclear: Failed to get status of the device loop2: No such device or address (g-bd-loop-error-quark, 1)
13:39:01 apparmor_parser: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap.cups.reject" pid=7201 comm="apparmor_parser"
13:39:01 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1695879541.846:153): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap.cups.cancel" pid=7177 comm="apparmor_parser"
13:39:01 apparmor_parser: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap.cups.cancel" pid=7177 comm="apparmor_parser"
13:39:01 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1695879541.838:149): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.chromium.chromedriver" pid=7168 comm="apparmor_parser"
13:39:01 apparmor_parser: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.chromium.chromedriver" pid=7168 comm="apparmor_parser"
13:39:01 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1695879541.826:148): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.chromium.chromium" pid=7169 comm="apparmor_parser"
13:39:01 apparmor_parser: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.chromium.chromium" pid=7169 comm="apparmor_parser"
13:39:01 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1695879541.762:147): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap-update-ns.chromium" pid=7167 comm="apparmor_parser"
13:39:01 apparmor_parser: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap-update-ns.chromium" pid=7167 comm="apparmor_parser"
13:39:01 systemd: Started tracker-extract-3.service - Tracker metadata extractor.
13:39:01 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1001 pid=3085] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Extract'
13:39:01 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1695879541.474:146): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.chromium.hook.configure" pid=7170 comm="apparmor_parser"
13:39:01 apparmor_parser: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.chromium.hook.configure" pid=7170 comm="apparmor_parser"
13:39:01 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1695879541.318:145): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="/snap/snapd/20092/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper" pid=7165 comm="apparmor_parser"
13:39:01 apparmor_parser: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="/snap/snapd/20092/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper" pid=7165 comm="apparmor_parser"
13:39:01 systemd: Starting tracker-extract-3.service - Tracker metadata extractor...
```

I think it has something to do with the amdgpu driver, but only guessing here. My system is up-to-date.
Feel free to ask for any specific logs. I will provide them.

Comment: I noticed that disabling the config variable `media.ffmpeg.vaapi.enabled` makes the browser not crash anymore. But this also mean that no hardware acceleration is possible anymore.